# Retrieve a list from Data store for django choicefield

Tags: django, datastore, choicefield

In forms.py, I defined the dropdown list as follow:

```
DEPARTMENT_CHOICES = (
    ('SALES', 'sales'),
    ('TECH', 'tech'),
    ('HR', 'hr'),)
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    department_s = forms.ChoiceField(
    widget=forms.SelectMultiple,
    choices=DEPARTMENT_CHOICES,
    required=True,)
```

It works fine in this way. But I want to retrieve the choice list from Google data store based on username dynamically. For example, if user1 is accessing to the form, then retrieve department list of his company(say company A). If user2 is accessing, then retrieve department list of his company (company B). User list and department list are stored in data store. I know that I may need to obtain the keys from data store, but really not sure how to do this right. Any body have sample codes for this case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use ModelChoiceField.

Comment: Yeah I`ve heard of that before. I will search for some sample codes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can write an init function for form like this

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    department_s = forms.ChoiceField(...)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # create department choice according to user
        query = Department.query(<any ndb query>).fetch
        DEPARTMENT_CHOICES = [[item.pk, unicode(item)] for item in query]
        self.fields['department_s'].choices = DEPARTMENT_CHOICES
```

when you want to initialize your form must pass user argument to it and it change department_s choices to what you want

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the answer. Do you know how to obtain the department choice from google data store instead of defining in here? Coz it can be a long list..and changeable.

Comment: you can set anything in department as you need. long list may cause many of ram usage. change of list affected on form init method. I update answer

Comment: Thank you! I will try query as you commented.